# Understanding nn.Sequential in convolutional layers

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am new to PyTorch/Deep learning and I am trying to understand the use of the following line to define a convolutional layer:

`self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv1d(input_dim, n_conv_filters, kernel_size=7, padding=0), nn.ReLU(), nn.MaxPool1d(3))`

I understand that that it is creating a 1d convolutional layer to the network with max pooling 3 wide. However, I don't understand the function of the sequential module or RelU. How do these function in creating a layer?

For reference, the rest of the code can be found here: https://github.com/ArdalanM/nlp-benchmarks/blob/master/src/cnn/net.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the description provided it seems you are in the process of developing a convolutional architecture for a problem (More likely a Computer Vision one as CNNs are usually targeted for solving CV problems).

Now talking about the code by using Sequential module you are telling the PyTorch that you are developing an architecture that will work in a sequential manner and by specifying ReLU you are bringing the concept of Non-Linearity in the picture (ReLU is one of the widely used activation functions in the Deep learning framework). Non-Linearity helps CNNs to generalize to complex decision boundaries and ultimately helps them to perform better.

PS: I recommend reviewing the https://towardsdatascience.com/convolutional-neural-network-for-image-classification-with-implementation-on-python-using-pytorch-7b88342c9ca9 for getting better idea from a coder perspective.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the link is very helpful. However, I have seen networks where they do not use nn.Sequential for each convolutional layer. Can CNN's not be sequential? I thought there had to be an order of layers which are processed sequentially.

Comment: I strongly believe, CNNs are always sequential in nature and there must be an order of how the internal layers of a network will process data. The training of the network is based on the concept of BACK-PROPAGATION which is highly dependent on the order of the layers. I request to please add links to those samples in which you are having doubt.

Comment: @SecProt The way your model/module works is defined in the forward method. It just happens that the forward of a nn.Sequential is basically calling the forward of every of its modules in a pre-defined sequence; in your case Conv1d -> ReLU -> MaxPooling.

Answer (score 0):

it is common way of creating model, simply using sequential class u are creating linear stacks of layers. You can also use functional API that allow you to create entirely arbitrary architectures.

Sequential model,

```
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
```

Functional API,

```
input_tensor = layers.Input(shape=(784,))
x = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(input_tensor)
output_tensor = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
model = models.Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=output_tensor)
```